# an array - how to display divs

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to display divs based on array. I'm using drag and drop for building my array and works fine. The problem I'm having: haw can I toggle div which has the same class/id as value form my array ?

```
var products = {
    pr1: {
        name: "Pr1 name",
        id: "myid"
    }
};
toCompare = [];
var compare = products[event.dataTransfer.getData('Text')]; //drag and drop
toCompare.push(compare.id); // works fine, I can see 'myid'
var comparenav = $('div#comparenav');
$.each(toCompare, function () {
    $(this).show();
});
<div id="comparenav" style="display: none;">lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` would just be `$("myid")`, but you need `$("#myid")`

```
$("#" + this).show();
```